# Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'id' does not exist in type 'ModelAttributes'

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

I am trying to define the database user model using sequelize ORM  but i am struggling with the type errors raised by typescript compiler  that I need help to resolve.
Code that I need to be resolved.

```
export interface IUserAddModel{
   email: string,
    password: string
 }

 export interface IUserModel extends Sequelize.Model<IUserModel,IUserAddModel>{
   id: number,
   email: string
   password: string
   createdAt?: string
   updatedAt?: string
}

export interface IUserViewModel{
    id: number,
    email: string
}


//Define a new model, representing a table in the DB.
export const User = sequelizeObj.define<IUserModel,IUserAddModel>('user', {
   id:{ // This id property is bringing about the type issue.. yet I defined in the 
        //IUserModel interface. Do not know why it is bring compiler error issues
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey:true
   },
   email: Sequelize.STRING,
   password: Sequelize.STRING 
})
```

**Error**

```
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'id' does not exist in type 'ModelAttributes<IUserModel, IUserAddModel>'
```

But when I remove the id from the defined model, the typescript compiler stops complaining but I need that id in the database table.

Comment: What version of sequelize and typescript you are using?

Comment: "sequelize": "6.3.5",
 "typescript": "3.9.7"

Comment: Take a look at https://sequelize.org/master/manual/typescript.html#usage-of--code-sequelize-define--code-